# How to get the App running both in the integrated and the standalone in single spa

Tags: reactjs, single-spa

Im new to Single Page Application (SPA).
I created 3 separate applications, where one is the root config app and the other two acts as the child applications.
We need to run one of these child applications separately on its own.

But the deployed application gives the following error:

[Your Microfrontend is not here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33vkM.png)

Can I know how to get it done
Locally it successfully runs when i run it from the

```
npm run start:standalone  command
```

Answer (score 5):

First: The "Error" you are getting is not an error. A microfrontend (mfe) is a microfrontend and a standalone application is a standalone application. There is a description on the Page of what you have to do to get it running.

I would not recommend running your single-spa MFE in standalone mode, for multiple Reasons which are also stated in the [Readme](https://github.com/single-spa/standalone-single-spa-webpack-plugin) of the standalone Plugin. It also basically just creates a standard small root-config for you to use.

But the biggest reason is that the standard yarn run serve:standalone doesn't create optimized builds, which leads to an increase in bundlesize.
E.G. one of my MFEs is 1mb big if build correctly but is around 13mb big if it's unoptimized. Which is quite noticeable.

If you want to run your Microfrontend without the other one you have two options in my opinion:

1. Create another Root-Config. Nothing is stopping you to create another
   Root-Config and only display a single Component on there. You can even deploy the build of your Root-Config to the same environment of your MFE you are displaying (i don't know your deployment process tho).
2. Create a Route on your Root-Config which only displays a single Component.

If you still opt to use standalone Mode you will need a Server/Dockercontainer with node and run it in there. I'm not aware of any Buildoutputs of the standalone plugin.