# SingleSpa Angular Microfrontend & Standalone application

Tags: angular, micro-frontend, single-spa, single-spa-angular

Is there a way to get an Angular application as both Microfrontend Sub-application and standalone application?

For example, I have a root config, on localhost:9000, and I have an angular single-spa application running on localhost:4200.

I can connect root with the angular app, such us I can see angular app by route on localhost:9000/app1. However, in the localhost:4200 is a empty page.

Is there a way to see angular app on both localhost:9000/app1, and localhost:4200 (as a stand alone application)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the App running both in the integrated and the standalone in single spa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70574818/how-to-get-the-app-running-both-in-the-integrated-and-the-standalone-in-single-s)

Comment: https://github.com/CanopyTax/single-spa-angular/issues/92 answer in this issue provide two config solution. Also, I saw somewhere mentioned about window.singleSpaNavigate, but not work for me. Any idea about that?

Comment: If you are using Vite projects, search for vite-plugin-single-spa.